# Set custom claims for ClaimsIdentity using IdentityServer4 authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application authenticated using IdentityServer4.TokenValidation

```cs
authenticationBuilder.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(AuthorizationConstants.IpreoAccountAuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.ApiName = apiName;
      options.ApiSecret = apiSecret;
      options.Authority = authority;
      options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
    });
```

What is the best way how can I add custom claims to identity?
Taking into account that we still need to have an opportunity to use Authorize attribute with Roles validation.

For bearer authentication for example we can use OnTokenValidated handler which is fired on each request. But for IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions Events property is of type of object and initializing it with a dummy object with OnTokenValidated property does not work.

*We have to support JWT and reference tokens.
Also we need to support multiple authentication schemes*

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Claims have to be added on the IdentityServer side. Your app using IdentityServer for auth can only work with what's sent to it. Although you can technically somewhat control the claims via the scopes your request, IdentityServer must already be set up to add certain claims based on those scopes.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thank you for your answer. Unfortunately our system was designed in a different manner and tokens from IdentityServer are used across multiple services with completely different set of permissions/claims gathered from multiple different places. So I am looking for a way how I can update/add another one identity inside my microservice when authentication is passed

Comment: And that's what I'm saying is not possible. IdentityServer sets the claims. What you can do is conditionally set claims for certain scopes and then request those scopes only in your apps that need those claims, but you cannot request a specific claim that is either not included in a scope or part of the default set returned by IdentityServer.

Comment: I can do it overriding IAuthorizationHandler, but in this case I have to duplicate a lot of build-in logic(like requirement validation etc) and I don't want to do it. Forms, JWT bearer, OpenId have OnTokenValidated or similar event, where I can inject adding the second identity, but I don't know how to apply the similar mechanism for IdentityServer

Comment: Don't use `AddIdentityServerAuthentication()`.  You can achieve the same and access the `Events` property by using `AddJwtBearer()`.

Comment: Brad, unfortunately we have to support reference tokens as well

Answer (score 1):

Ruard van Elburg gave me a good idea about using a middleware. The only thing I had to update use this approach for multiple authentication schemes was overriding IAuthenticationSchemeProvider to keep using UseAuthentication middleware.

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/beaa2b443d46ef8adaf5c2a89eb475e1893037c2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs

So it returns default scheme based on a request content

What I had to do:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware<ClaimsMiddleware>(); // to set claims for authenticated user
    app.UseMvc();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);    
    services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider, CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider>(); 
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddAuthentication // add authentication for multiple schemes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need middleware for that. As an example, I suggest you take a look at the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/). It has the same approach.

IdentityServer handles the authentication, while authorization is handled by the PolicyServer. The [free OSS version](https://policyserver.io/) adds claims in the middleware.

From the source code:

```cs
/// Add the policy server claims transformation middleware to the pipeline.
/// This middleware will turn application roles and permissions into claims
/// and add them to the current user
public static IApplicationBuilder UsePolicyServerClaims(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    return app.UseMiddleware<PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware>();
}
```

Where PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware is:

```cs
public class PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The next.</param>
    public PolicyServerClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="client">The client.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IPolicyServerRuntimeClient client)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var policy = await client.EvaluateAsync(context.User);

            var roleClaims = policy.Roles.Select(x => new Claim("role", x));
            var permissionClaims = policy.Permissions.Select(x => new Claim("permission", x));

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity("PolicyServerMiddleware", "name", "role");
            id.AddClaims(roleClaims);
            id.AddClaims(permissionClaims);

            context.User.AddIdentity(id);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And from startup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvcCore(options =>
    {
        // workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7809
        options.AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters = false;
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddAuthorization();

    // This is not relevant for you, but just to show how policyserver is implemented.
    // The bottom line is that you can implement this anyway you like.

    // this sets up the PolicyServer client library and policy
    // provider - configuration is loaded from appsettings.json
    services.AddPolicyServerClient(Configuration.GetSection("Policy"))
            .AddAuthorizationPermissionPolicies();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // add this middleware to make roles and permissions available as claims
    // this is mainly useful for using the classic [Authorize(Roles="foo")] and IsInRole functionality
    // this is not needed if you use the client library directly or the new policy-based authorization framework in ASP.NET Core
    app.UsePolicyServerClaims();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ruard, that is a great suggestion, but we use multiple AuthenticationSchemes inside of Auhtorize attribute and context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be false for a non-default handler. Maybe we should should call authentication handlers in a different way, but I am not sure how